# Connected Bipartite Vertex-transitive Graph Recognition

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, bipartite-graphs

For vertex-transitive graphs, the computational complexity of recognizing them is still unknown. So here comes the question: if it is guaranteed that the input graph is bipartite and connected,  is the computational complexity of determining whether it is vertex-transitive or not known now?

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but just pointing out some relationships between the problems.

**(1)** The problem for bipartite graphs is as hard as the general problem for arbitrary graphs, this much we can prove.
**(2)** Similarly, the problem for *connected* bipartite graphs is no easier than the general problem for *connected* graphs.

To see this, we need a result from *Vertex-Transitive Direct Products of Graphs* by Hammack and Imrich (available for free via the Electronic Journal of Combinatorics).

The result is as follows:
**Theorem 13:** *If $A$ and $B$ are both non-bipartite or both bipartite, then $A \times B$ is vertex transitive if and only if both $A$ and $B$ are vertex-transitive.
If $A$ has an odd cycle and $B$ is bipartite, then $A \times B$ is vertex-transitive if and only if both $A \times K_2$ and $B$ are vertex transitive.*

Using the second part of the theorem, we can see that for any non-bipartite graph $A$, the (bipartite!) graph $A\times K_2$ is vertex transitive if and only if $A$ is. So for a non-bipartite graph $A$, you can reduce the problem of determining whether it's vertex-transitive to the same problem on the bipartite graph $K_2\times A$. This proves statement **(1)**.

Further note that for a non-bipartite $A$, $K_2\times A$ is connected if and only if $A$ is, demonstrating **(2)**.